# How to make row into a column using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have something like this:

```
student1 |  2015-10-01 |    100  |
student2 |  2015-10-02 |    75   |
student3 |  2015-10-03 |    90   |
```

---

and I want this:

```
Names    | 2015-10-01 | 2015-10-02 | 2015-10-03 |
Student1 |     100    |     -      |     -      |
Student2 |            |    75      |     -      |
Student3 |      -     |     -      |    90      |
```

---

By the way, dates are unlimited.

Comment: That -1 is me myself. tried to vote for myself. didnt know that was illegal. lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

i think you use  GROUP BY to simulate a PIVOT:

SELECT Id,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Order = 1 THEN data END) data1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN Order = 2 THEN data END) data2
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Id

Check Example: [Click Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc8eb/1)